# Connection String retrieved from one DB to be used in a Class Library to access a 2nd DB...Suggestions?

Tags: sql, .net, connection-string, class-library

**Environment:**
.Net, SQL Server, WinForms Desktop

Control Database (db1)
Customer Databases (db2, db3, db4, etc.)

**Background:**
Each of our customers requires their own database.  It's a contractual obligation due to compliance with standards in certain industries.  Certain users of our application only have access to specific databases.

**Scenario:**
The application user's username gets passed into our control database (db1) from the app on load.  There's a lookup in there that determines what customer this user has access to and returns connection string info for connecting to the database of the determined customer (db2 or db3 or db4 or etc.) to be used for the life of the runtime.  All of my business logic is in a DAL, as it should be, in a .Net class library.

Suggestions on the best way/ways to get the connection string information into the DAL WITHOUT passing into every constructor/method that is called on the DAL.

I came up with one possible solution, but want to pick your brains to see if there's another or better way.

**Possible Solutions:**

- A Global module in the DAL that has public fields like "dbServer" and "dbName". 
  Set those and then use the DAL as needed.  They would need to be set each time the DAL is used throughout the application, but at least I don't have to make the signature of every single constructor and method require connection string information.
- A settings file (preferably XML) that the app writes to after getting the connection info and the DAL reads from for the life of the runtime.

Thoughts and/or suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the only difference connection string or the code in the data access is different too?

Comment: The customer databases are identical, just different data.  The API (DAL) is the same regardless.

Answer (score 0):

A set up like this might help. If you are going the IoC way, then you can remove the parameterized constructor and make Connection object a dependency too. However, you will need to feed your dependency injection provider in code since connection string comes from database.

```
   public class User
    {
        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    public class SomeBusinessEntity
    {

    }

    public class CallerClass
    {
        public IBaseDataAccess<SomeBusinessEntity> DataAccess
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void DoSomethingWithDatabase(User user)// Or any other way to access current user
        {
            // Either have specific data access initialized 
            SpecificDataAccess<SomeBusinessEntity> specificDataAccess = new SpecificDataAccess<SomeBusinessEntity>(user.ConnectionString);
            // continue

            // have dependency injection here as well. Your IoC configuration must ensure that it does not kick in until we get user object
            DataAccess.SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    public interface IBaseDataAccess<T>
    {
        IDbConnection Connection
        {
            get;
        }

        void SomeMethod();

        // Other common stuff
    }

    public abstract class BaseDataAccess<T> : IBaseDataAccess<T>
    {
        private string _connectionString;
        public BaseDataAccess(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public virtual IDbConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            }
        }

        public abstract void SomeMethod();

        // Other common stuff

    }

    public class SpecificDataAccess<T> : BaseDataAccess<T>
    {
        public SpecificDataAccess(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
        }

        public override void SomeMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SomeSpecificMethod()
        {
            using (Connection)
            {
                // Do something here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  I will consume this later and see if I like it as a solution.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @chase note that it is not a complete example. If specific data access have their own specific methods, you might want to use interfaces for them as well and put those in caller.

Comment: I gotcha.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Create a *ConnectionStringProvider* class that will  provide you the connection string**

```c#
    public class ConnectionStringProvider 
    {
         // store it statically so that every instance of connectionstringprovider 
         //   uses the same value        
        private static string _customerConnectionString;

        public string GetCustomerConnectionString()
        {
            return _customerConnectionString;
        }

        public void SetCustomerConnectionString(string connectionString)
        {
            _customerConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
    }
```

**Using *ConnectionStringProvider* in your DAL**

```c#
    public class MyCustomerDAL
    {
        private ConnectionStringProvider _connectionStringProvider;

        public MyCustomerDAL()
        {
            _connectionStringProvider = new ConnectionStringProvider();
        }

        public void UpdateSomeData(object data)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(
                  connectionString: _connectionStringProvider.GetCustomerConnectionString()))
            {
                //do something awesome with the connection and data
            }
        }
    }
```

**Setting/changing the connection string**

```c#
    new ConnectionStringProvider()
        .SetCustomerConnectionString(connString);
```

**Note**
The reason i chose to use method instead of a get/set property in ConnectionStringProvider is because maybe in the future you decide to read/write these from a file,  and while you could read/write from file in a property it's misleading to your consumer who thinks that a property will be a simple performance-less hit.
Using a function tells your consumer there might be some performance hit here, so use it wisely.

#### A little abstration for unit testing

Here is a slight variation that will enable you to abstract for unit testing (and eventually IoC)

```c#
    public class MyCustomerDAL
    {
        private IConnectionStringProvider _connectionStringProvider;

        public MyCustomerDAL()
        {
            //since not using IoC, here you have to explicitly new it up
            _connectionStringProvider = new ConnectionStringProvider();
        }

        //i know you don't want constructor, i included this to demonstrate how you'd override for writing tests
        public MyCustomerDAL(IConnectionStringProvider connectionStringProvider)
        {
            _connectionStringProvider = connectionStringProvider;
        }

        public void UpdateSomeData(object data)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(
             connectionString: _connectionStringProvider.GetCustomerConnectionString()))
            {
                //do something awesome with the connection and data
            }
        }
    }

    // this interface lives either in a separate abstraction/contracts library
    //     or it could live inside of you DAL library
    public interface IConnectionStringProvider
    {
        string GetCustomerConnectionString();
        void SetCustomerConnectionString(string connectionString);
    }

    public class ConnectionStringProvider : IConnectionStringProvider
    {
        // store it statically so that every instance of connectionstringprovider uses the same value
        private static string _customerConnectionString;

        public string GetCustomerConnectionString()
        {
            return _customerConnectionString;
        }

        public void SetCustomerConnectionString(string connectionString)
        {
            _customerConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
    }
```

#### Appendix A - Using IoC and DI

Disclaimer: the goal of this next piece about IoC is not to say one way is right or wrong, it's merely to bring up the idea as another way to approach solving the problem.

For this particular situation Dependency Injection would make your solving the problem super simple;  specifically if you were using an IoC container combined with constructor injection.

I don't mean it would make the code more simple, that would be more or less the same, it would make the mental side of "how do I easily get some service into every DAL class?" an easy answer; **inject it**.

I know you said you don't want to change the constructor. That's cool, you don't want to change it because it is a pain to change all the places of instantiation.

However, if everything were being created by IoC, you would not care about adding to constructors because you would never invoke them directly.

Then, you could add services like your new IConnectionStringProvider right to the constructor and be done with it.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I am not seeing how I get the connection string information from DB1 into my DAL.